# Is there a tag on MSE for the block of links under the post body and above the comments?

Tags: support, tags, hyperlinks, terminology

Is there a tag that can be used for questions related to the block of links under the post body? (share, edit, close, delete, flag)

> [image]

If there's not, how can we name it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That menu under each post is called the "post menu". The tag here on Meta Stack Exchange is [post-menu](/questions/tagged/post-menu). In each Stack Exchange page where a post is displayed, the menu is, currently, identified in the HTML by the `js-post-menu` class.

Comment: I have never heard of this, and it looks like almost none of the people posting here have either — most questions about it don't have the tag.

Comment: @Laurel despite that there's low vote activity on Q.